# DLL load failed while importing pyrfc: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pyrfc

I have a problem with pyrfc.

I import the module like this in code

```
from pyrfc import Connection
```

If I try to do pip install I get this message

> Requirement already satisfued: pyrfc in d:\users\andrei_stanculescu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
> Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64_qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from pyrfc) (58.1.0)

I run it with Visual Studio Code, what can I do, I don't know how to resolve this. The version of pyrfc is 2.0.4

Comment: try to install  pyrfc 2.5 .

Answer (score 0):

SAP RFC SDK could be for different platform, or not found, or platform prerequisites not met, or similar installation issue. Some troubleshooting hints: https://github.com/SAP/node-rfc/blob/main/doc/installation.md#troubleshooting and in PyRFC documentation